# SharePoint Online - is there any event or scheduled action to sync item level permission when it changes?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, provider-hosted-app, remote-event-receiver, item-level-permissions

Let's say I have 2 Document Libraries, Lib_A and Sub_A, in a SharePoint Online site.

When there is an item in Lib_A of ID `X`, there will also be an item in Sub_A, using `X` as item title.

Now I am looking for some automated method, which:

> when user changes the item-level permission of the item X in Lib_A,
> corresponding item in Sub_A should copy the same permission automatically

Under the following Assumption:

- directly or not, I cannot "write down" user credential anywhere (e.g. for a CSOM console program and run it as scheduled task)
- titles or permissions of items in Sub_A will not be modified manually
- any user with rights to change item level permission in Lib_A may have identitical permission on Sub_A
- permission changes of an item may not necessarily update the item itself
- tools I can use(which I can think of right now): Power Automate and Provider-Hosted App

Please give me some suggestion on what I should be looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Hello William, you can apply that using Power Automate and SharePoint REST Api, it suit you ?

Comment: There is not Power Automate trigger for your scenario or there is not event receiver available for your scenario i.e. when permission is changed.

Here you have to create PowerShell /  Console with CSOM/ Azure Function which sync permission